# Explanation of last step in proof of Lemma 4.2 in paper "An Axiomatic Approach to Forcing in a General Setting"

Tags: proof-explanation, forcing

The paper "An Axiomatic Approach to Forcing in a General Setting" by R. Freire and P Holy includes the proof of Lemma 4.2.

(Note that in the paper a 'generic filter' means a filter in a partial order P and C is a class of sets and $F_G()$ is a valuation under G and other items are in the notes under the question).

My question is : what is the reasoning behind the last step ?

**Lemma 4.2. Let D $\in$ C be such that D is dense in P. If G is a generic filter, then G intersects D.**

**Proof.**

Let G be a generic filter and assume for a contradiction that G $\cap$ D = $\emptyset$.

Making use of axioms (*) and (**), it follows that

$$M[G] \models \neg \exists x \; x \in F_G (\check{D}) \cap F_G(\dot{G}) $$

By axiom (4 - the Truth Lemma), we may thus find p $\in$ G such that

$$p \Vdash \neg \exists x \; x \in \check{D} \cap \dot{G} $$

By Lemma 4.1, equivalently

$$\forall q  \leq p \; \neg [q \Vdash \exists x \; x \in \check{D} \cap \dot{G}] $$

Since D is dense, we may fix q $\leq$ p in D.

**Last step:**

But then

$$ q \Vdash \check{q} \in \check{D} \cap \dot{G}$$

so contradicting the above.

**So the question is** : what is the reasoning behind "But then $ q \Vdash \check{q} \in \check{D} \cap \dot{G}$"

i.e. why should G contain the q $\leq$ p that is in D ?

**Notes :**

(*) Names for ground model objects

$ \forall a \in M \; \exists \check{a} \in M \; \forall  G \; F_G(\check{a}) = a $

(**) Name for generic filters

$\exists \dot{G} \in C \; \forall G \; F_G(\dot{G})=G$

**Lemma 4.1** : $ p \Vdash \neg \varphi \iff \forall q \leq p \; \neg [q \Vdash \varphi]$

Answer (score 0):

The reason is axiom (5) Definability Lemma. For every $q$, it is true that $q$ forces that $G$ contains $q$ (which is the interpretation of $\check q\in\dot G$).